# How to properly sort alphanumeric in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2000

MS SQL Server 2000

I have a column in Table A called Name. I wish to sort the Name field. Many but not all of the records for Name start will KL and are followed by a number (KL 1234, KL 2, KL 323, etc).

### Table A

### Name

Able
Bravo
KL 2
KL 323
KL 1234
Zebra

If I use

```
Select Name from A 
Order by Name
```

I get

Able
Bravo
KL 1234
KL 2
KL 323
Zebra

I want

Able
Bravo
KL 2
KL 323
KL 1234
Zebra

If they all started with KL I could use

```
Select Name from A
Order by cast(replace(name, 'KL', '') as big int)
```

but this generates an "unble to cast name as big int" error for values that do not start with KL

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Order By 
    Case When Left(name, 2) = 'KL' 
        Then 'KL' + Replace(Str(Cast(replace(name, 'KL', '') as BigInt), 12), ' ', '0')
        Else name End
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', name)=0 THEN name 
        ELSE LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)) END,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', name)=0 THEN 0
        ELSE CONVERT(BIGINT, 
            SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name)+1, LEN(name))) END
```

updated wrong closing ) after comment

Comment: I received a "The substring function requires 3 arguments" error with this. I didn't play with it though as I was just seeing if it worked out of the box. I like this approach as it appears more generic and would work with independent of what the prefix is. Thanks.